# How can I write a non-editable and scrollable data in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to make a messenger. I made it with the socket library.
Now I want to make a GUI for it in tkinter.
I want to store messages in a scrollable box that cannot be edited.
(You know, like any messengers nowadays. )
Do you know a good method to do this?

Comment: The text widget is scrollable and can be disabled. Have you tried that?

Comment: i did not know. let me try it.

Comment: how to change the text of text widget?

Comment: The methods of the text widget are documented. There are methods for inserting text and deleting text.